# Android How do I set different spacing for each viewpage item?

Tags: android

I know that there is a method in the ViewPage called setPageMargin that sets the spacing for each item, but I want to set the spacing for each item to be different now.

Like addItemDecoration in recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

~.~setPageMargin ?Like addItemDecoration in recyclerview?!
you can use this lib

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2

//ViewPager2 is recylerView